# Tweepy error (AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'request')

Tags: python, tweepy, attributeerror

Hey guys I'm by no means a developer and know very little about python.
When I try to run some code I found in internet (I know it's a bad habit but it seem harmless) i get this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mauro\Desktop\Nuova cartella\new 1.py", line 23, in <module>
    friends = tweepy.API.get_friend_ids(screen_name)
  File "C:\Users\Mauro\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\tweepy\api.py", line 33, in wrapper
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Mauro\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\tweepy\api.py", line 46, in wrapper
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Mauro\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\tweepy\api.py", line 2131, in get_friend_ids
    return self.request(
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'request'
```

This is the code I'm trying to run. I purposely left out my api keys

```
# import the module
import tweepy

# assign the values accordingly
consumer_key = '...'
consumer_secret = '...'
access_token = '...'
access_token_secret = '...'

# authorization of consumer key and consumer secret
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)

# set access to user's access key and access secret
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

# calling the api
api = tweepy.API(auth)

# screen name of the user
screen_name = "coinbase"

# getting the friends list
friends = tweepy.API.get_friend_ids(screen_name)

print(screen_name + " is following :")
for friend in friends:
    print(tweepy.api.get_user(friend).screen_name)
```

Comment: Should `tweepy.API.get_friend_ids` be `api.get_friend_ids`?

Answer (score 0):

You're using `tweepy.API`, the class, instead of `api`, your instance of it.
`API.get_friend_ids` is not a class method.